# jqgrid full screen switch, window width and height

Tags: jqgrid, resize, window, switch-statement, fullscreen

How would this be possible to switch between full screen and normal view?

for example: tiny mce editor has the same function.

Any ideas in js ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly understand the question 
But if you are looking for resizing jqgrid  on browser resize this might be helpful

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    jQuery("#grid").setGridWidth($('#parentDiv').width()-30, true);
}).trigger('resize');
```